# Ruby shorthand for adding items to array in each loop

Tags: ruby

I feel like i've seen this question somewhere before but i cannot find it and i'm pretty sure ruby has a one liner for looping over something and adding the items to an array:

```
items = []
some_stuff.each do |stuff|
  items << stuff
end
items
```

Comment: `Enumerable#reduce` or `Enumerable#each_with_object` would do the job

Comment: reduce is not necessary, he is not asking the summation. He simply wants to push one array into another.

Comment: And who said `reduce` is only for summation? Reduce is Ruby's answer to `fold` HOF and it _can_ do this job perfectly fine. Which one to pick is just a matter of personal preferences or conventions

Comment: From your example, it looks like `items = some_stuff.dup` is all you need. Or maybe `items.concat(some_stuff)` to append to an existing array.

Comment: Do you mean to use [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), e.g. `items = some_stuff.map { |stuff| stuff.whatever }`? Your initial example is probably too simplified for what you *actually* intend to do.

Answer (score 1):

this way?

```
items = some_stuff.inject([]) { |acc, item| acc + [item] }
```

obviously this exact snippet doesn't make sense because it's another array with the same value, you could just dup `some_stuff`, but I think can help you anyway

Comment: He is not asking for summation of the items, he is asking for adding into the array which he simply can assign it.

Comment: I'm not adding anything. I do not mutate the object, that's all

Comment: Ah!!! sorry, I misunderstood you. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Note that this creates two new arrays on each iteration: one for `[item]` and one as the result of `acc + [item]`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
some_stuff=[1,2,3,4,6,7]
```

Code

```
items=some_stuff.each_with_object([]){|value,items|items.push(value)}
p items
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

If `some_stuff` responds to `each`, then it very likely also conforms to the [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) protocol. (It would be silly not to, since `each` is all you need to support the `Enumerable` protocol via `include Enumerable`.)

The `Enumerable` protocol includes the method [`Enumerable#to_a`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a), which returns the elements of the `Enumerable` as an [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html):

> ## `to_a` → `array`
>
> Returns an array containing the items in `self`:
>
> ```ruby
> (0..4).to_a # => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
> ```

So, assuming that `some_stuff` really does conform to the `Enumerable` protocol, all you need to do is

```ruby
items = some_stuff.to_a
```

*However*, unless you absolutely *need* the specific features an `Array` provides, there is no need to even do this. If `some_stuff` really does conform to the `Enumerable` protocol, then most of the methods that you would use on the `Array` already exist on `some_stuff` as well, and they *may* even be more efficient because `some_stuff` knows more about what its internal structure is and what the structure of the elements is than `Array` does.

There is often no need to convert an `Enumerable` to an `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use splat operator if working with an array

```rb
items = [*some_stuff]
```